# Foreign Key Reference 2 columns with OR Construction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints, foreign-key-relationship

I need to do some migrations on our database and I have a problem.

A column *(AirportCodeDeparture)* in my table can refer to either *AirportCode* or *AirportMetropolitanCode* from the *Airport* Table. **Note:** this does not mean that a *AirportCodeDeparture* is a *AirportCode* **AND** a *AirportMetropolitanCode*, no, this is the **OR** part of my problem.

[image: db scheme]

So I try to create a table that corresponds to this situation but I don't quit know how to implement the OR part of the foreign key references.

This is what I have now:

```
CREATE TABLE FlightAllotment
(
    FlightAllotmentId smallint not null IDENTITY(1,1), CONSTRAINT PK_FlightAllotmentId PRIMARY KEY (FlightAllotmentId),

    AirportCodeDeparture char(5) not null, CONSTRAINT FK_FlightAllotment_AirportCodeDeparture FOREIGN KEY (AirportCodeDeparture) REFERENCES Airport(AirportCode) OR Airport(AirportMetropolitanCode),
)
```

This part: `REFERENCES Airport(AirportCode) OR Airport(AirportMetropolitanCode)`

I already tried

```
REFERENCES Airport(AirportCode) || Airport(AirportMetropolitanCode)

REFERENCES Airport(AirportCode || AirportMetropolitanCode)

REFERENCES Airport(AirportCode OR AirportMetropolitanCode)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why your application can't convert the metropolitan codes to regular airport codes for insertion into FlightAllotment?

Comment: Add a column to airport indicating the type of airport (metropolitan, etc).  Transfer records from AirportMetropolitan to Airport.  Drop the AirportMetropolitanKey column from Airport.

Comment: I can't do that, you need to see a metropolitan as an area with multiple airports. And a metropolitan has a default airport. For example, if you want to travel to Milan, Malpensa airport will be default. But sometimes we have a package for a trip to Milan, that uses a particular airline that only flies on another airport, so the default airport for the metropolitan needs to be overriden

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, I'm afraid. The target of an FK needs to be a unique key on the target table, and can only be one column as well. There is no OR allowed.

One way to do this is to an entry in Airport for the parent AirportMetropolitan and then refer to that entry, but I don't know how sensible that would be.

The other way is to have FlightAllotment.AirportDepartureCode be an FK to Airport but nullable so you don't have to supply it when you want to use an AirportMetropolitan code. You could also add FlightAllotment.AirportMetropolitanDepartureCode as an FK to AirportMetropolitan.AirportMetropolitanCode, also as a nullable column.

Those are your options I'm afraid.

Comment: I'd add that another (ugly) option is to not use the foreign key constraint. It could lead to corrupt data in FlightAllotment (though it seems unlikely that airport codes will often change or be deleted), and you'd have to hand-code your joins in your application code.

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure that FlightAllotment.AirportDepartureCode should be nullable.  It seems like you can always get the AirportCode if you have the AirportMetropolitanCode. It's an extra query which could weigh on performance, but a null value in the field seems misleading to me.

Comment: Hi @aro_tech - It's not having an FK that leads to corruption: having an FK stops the deletion of an Airport where any flight refers to it. For your second point, in the data model above having a Metropolitan code gives you possibly many Airports: which one are you going to pick? That was the point of my first suggestion.

Comment: Looked like a 1-to-1 in his diagram, but you're right. I understand the domain better now. If the AirportMetropolitanCode does not specify just 1 airport, the airport code has to be nullable.  About corruption, you may have misinterpreted my first comment above.. What I meant in my earlier comment was that if you do not have a FK constraint, you can reference an airport that no longer exists.  You are right about the FK preventing deletion, as well. That's why I called the option of not having an FK "ugly" (along with the need for application code to sort out the right ID).